# complex restructuring of (already wide) data with items of different length

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I want to restructure my data set. Therefore, I need kind of a restructuring from long to wide. The difficulty for me is that I do already have something like a wide format which I would like to make even wider. But therefore I could not find any comparable posts to do this restructuring process.

So this is my data set as it looks like at the moment:

[image]

or shown with str() function:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1651 obs. of  13 variables:


$ passcode     : chr  "AN04AD" "AN04AD" "AN04AD" "AN04AD" ...
 $ question_id  : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ question_type: chr  "TrueOrFalse" "TrueOrFalse" "TrueOrFalse" "TrueOrFalse" ...
 $ option_1     : num  1 1 1 1 1 0 NA 0 1 0 ...
 $ option_2     : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 NA 1 0 1 ...
 $ option_3     : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 NA 1 0 1 ...
 $ option_4     : num  0 0 0 0 2 1 NA 0 1 0 ...
 $ option_5     : num  0 0 0 0 2 0 NA 0 0 0 ...
 $ option_6     : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 NA 0 0 0 ...
 $ option_7     : num  NA NA NA NA 2 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ option_8     : num  NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ created_at   : POSIXct, format: "2021-06-03 18:28:16" "2021-06-03 18:28:16" "2021-06-03 18:28:16" "2021-06-03 18:28:16" ...
 $ updated_at   : POSIXct, format: NA NA NA NA ..
```

After restructuring it should look like:

[image]

This means for each person (passcode) I just need one row in the data set.
Overall, I have 11 items (question_id) and 1529 rows what make 139 different passcodes.
The Items (question_id) vary in their number of answer options but the maximum of these answer options is 8 presented answers. The Item 1 (question_id = 1), e.g. has just 6 answer options why (after the restructuring process) the new variables "question1_option7" and "question1_option8" has just NAs.
During the restructuring process, I would like the "option_x"-variables to be renames like: question1_option1, question1_option2 and so on.

Comment: Please avoid sharing photos of data. Use `dput()` to create a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `pivot_wider()` from `dplyr`

```
df <- tibble(passcode = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 2),
             question_id = rep(1:2, times = 10),
             questionType = "TrueOrFalse",
             option_1 = round(runif(min = 0, max = 3, 20)),
             option_2 = round(runif(20)))

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = 'question_id',
                   values_from = c('option_1', 'option_2'),
                   id_cols = 'passcode')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mzbua. For me, your command worked like this:

df_presurvey <- df_presurvey %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = question_id,
              values_from = option_1:option_8,
              id_cols = 'passcode')`


Do you also know how to "copy" also the variable "created_at" when restructuring the data?

Comment: Include it in the `id_cols`